# How to get element's width/height within directives and component?

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular-components

```js
@Component({
    selector: '.donation',
    template: `
    <figure id="donation" move>
        <img src="image/qrcode.png"/>
        <figcaption>
        Buy me a cup of coffee.
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
    `
})
export class DonationComponent{}

@Directive({
    selector: '[move]'
})
export class MoveDirective{}
```

Hey, I want to get the `<figure id="donation">` element's width/height within `MoveDirective` and `DonationComponent`. I have read the documentation several times but still cannot find a way to this answer. Does somebody know this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use **ElementRef** as shown below,

**DEMO : https://plnkr.co/edit/XZwXEh9PZEEVJpe0BlYq?p=preview** check browser's console.

```js
import { Directive, Input, Output, ElementRef, Renderer } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector:"[move]",
  host:{
    '(click)':"show()"
  }
})

export class GetEleDirective{
  
  constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }

  show(){
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement);
    
    console.log('height---' + this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight);  //<<<===here
    console.log('width---' + this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth);    //<<<===here
  }
}
```

Same way you can use it within component itself wherever you need it.

Comment: Thanks a lot,It works perfect!But I am still a little confused about why using offsetHeight but not the height property to get the element's height?

Comment: `ElementRef` has been marked as security risk: https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/core/index/ElementRef-class.html - is it still ok to use it?

Comment: @shiva there isn't a risk, since you are also extracting information from the DOM, not inserting dangerous elements.

Comment: What about the case if children of host element have bigger width or height than the host. How can we get correct width and height of host element?

Comment: Can this be set to handle resize events? Or is that really hacky?

Comment: @Simon_Weaver: Yes you can do it or you can use `windows.resize()` event also  but google it so you will come to know more about it.

Comment: @micronyks looking like ngDoCheck() and testing inside for _ele.nativeElement.clientWidth is one way. Obviously being careful to not trigger an action every time it’s called! Seems to be working for what i need (homemade responsive design). Thx

Answer (score 38):

For a bit more flexibility than with micronyks answer, you can do it like that:

**1.** In your template, add `#myIdentifier` to the element you want to obtain the width from. Example:

```html
<p #myIdentifier>
  my-component works!
</p>
```

**2.** In your controller, you can use this with `@ViewChild('myIdentifier')` to get the width:

```js
import {AfterViewInit, Component, ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-component',
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-component.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponentComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
  }

  @ViewChild('myIdentifier')
  myIdentifier: ElementRef;

}
```

---

**Security**

About the security risk with `ElementRef`, like this, there is none. There would be a risk, if you would **modify** the DOM using an ElementRef. But here you are only *getting* DOM Elements so there is no risk. A risky example of using `ElementRef` would be: `this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.onclick = someFunctionDefinedBySomeUser;`. Like this Angular doesn't get a chance to use its sanitisation mechanisms since `someFunctionDefinedBySomeUser` is inserted *directly* into the DOM, *skipping* the Angular sanitisation.

Comment: How does this handle resize events?

Comment: It doesn't, but you can add a @HostListener window:resize, see e.g. https://scotch.io/tutorials/responsive-equal-height-with-angular-directive#toc-wait-are-we-done-yet

Comment: tried to follow your example but "this.myIdentifier" returns undefined...

Comment: Try this link for resize event. https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-resize-event

Answer (score 0):

@ViewChild doesn't work for everybody- at least, not for me. I'm using Angular 9. What *did work* was using @ViewChildren:

```
@ViewChildren('myIdentifier')
myIdentifier: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myIdentifier.changes.subscribe((identifiers) => {
    console.log("OFFSET WIDTH", identifiers.first.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
  });
}
```

Comment: `@ViewChild` works always, when you ask for the element, the element was in the app. If you has under a `*ngIf="condition"` and the condition is not fullfilled, Angular can found it. If your condition is false and makes the condition true but you don't wait Angular "repaint", Angular can not find it -typical you enclosed in a setTimeout() to give time Angular "repaint"-

Comment: @Eliseo ngAfterViewInit is run only once, if I use *ngIf to see if myIdentifier returns a truthy value, it will just return false, won't it? Should I place this condition in another lifecycle hook?

Comment: Lybelle, yes ngAfterViewInit is run only one. But ViewChild "check" if exist or not unless you use `@ViewChild('...',{static:true})` -static true, makes Angular don't "check" the element-. But if you use `@ViewChild()` without "static:true" Angular "check if exist or not" the element (imagine like a `@Input` that can have two values "true/false"). So you can make some like: `click(){this.condition=true;setTimeout(()=>{console.log(this.element.nativeElement.offsetWidth})`. a little example in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mo5bj7?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const rowHeight = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector('.datagrid-table > .datagrid-row').getBoundingClientRect().height;
```

https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer

Inspired by this [getting 'nativeElement.querySelector is not a function' exception in Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42403857/getting-nativeelement-queryselector-is-not-a-function-exception-in-angular2/42568149#42568149)