# getting 'nativeElement.querySelector is not a function' exception in Angular2

Tags: angular, angular-universal, viewchild

I'm trying to access a div in Angular2 like below:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, ElementRef, AfterContentInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: `
    <div  #target class="parent">
        <div class="child">
        </div>
    </div>
  `
})

export class MainComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ViewChild('target') elementRef: ElementRef;

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        var child = this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector('div');
        console.log(child);
    }
}
```

but I get the following exception:

> Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: TypeError:
>   this.elementRef.nativeElement.querySelector is not a function

Comment: That is strange the `ElementRef.nativeElement` is type `any`. What version of angular are you using or what dose your `package.json` look like?

Comment: i'm using angular 2.0.0. shouldn't work with this version?

Comment: It should work an it works here https://plnkr.co/edit/fRsQot7KtIAUGSIIZdKA

Comment: yes, it should work but it doesn't. i also upgrade my project to Angular 2.4.5 but still the same result. i can't understand why.

Comment: Can you post the full code, with it not working somewhere?

Comment: i'm using http://www.telerik.com/blogs/cooking-with-aspnet-core-and-angular-2 template for my project which has the issue. but when i use plnkr is working fine. also if i use a simple angular2 project without this template is working fine as well

Answer (score 3):

That template uses `angular2-universal` for server-side rendering.
https://github.com/angular/universal#universal-gotchas

Try:

```
import { Component, AfterContentInit, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: `
    <div  #target class="parent">
        <div class="child">
        </div>
    </div>
`
})
export class MainComponent implements AfterContentInit {
    @ViewChild('target') elementRef: ElementRef;

    constructor(private renderer: Renderer) {}

    ngAfterContentInit(): void {
        var child = (this.elementRef.nativeElement as any).querySelector.apply(this.elementRef.nativeElement, ['div']);
        console.log(child);
    }
}
```

https://angular.io/guide/migration-renderer

Comment: This is now deprecated. Does any one have an updated answer?

Comment: `const rowHeight = (el as any).querySelector.apply(el, ['.datagrid-table > .datagrid-row']).getBoundingClientRect().height;`