# How to get size of a child component in angular 2?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to center a modal. It contains other components, so the position depends on the content. I'm trying to get it this way, which doesn't work and not sure how to fix it:

component HTML:

```
  <div #modal [style.top]="positionTop" [style.left]="positionLeft">
    <app-modal-one *ngIf="feature==='one'"> </app-modal-one>
    <app-modal-two *ngIf="feature==='two'"></app-modal-two>
    <app-modal-three *ngIf="feature==='three'"></app-modal-three>
  </div>
```

component ts:

```
@ViewChild('modal') private modalContent: ElementRef;
ngOnInit() {
    this.modalHeight = this.modalContent.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.modalWidth = this.modalContent.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.positionLeft = (window.innerWidth - this.modalWidth) / 2 + "px";
    this.positionTop = (window.innerHeight - this.modalHeight) / 2 + "px";
    console.log("on init: "+this.modalWidth)    
  }
```

The console log shows the size as 0.
If I check it later once it's displayed, it shows the right size. When and how can I get this size (of the #modal) before/or just after it's all displayed?

Comment: Try `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit`

Comment: I get Exception: Expression has changed after it was checked if I use AfterViewInit or AfterViewChecked

Comment: I see. add `constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}` and as last line in `ngAfterViewInit` `this.cdRef.detectChanges()`

Comment: Using `ngAfterViewInit ` adn `this.cdRef.detectChanges()` worked! Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get element's width/height within directives and component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813269/how-to-get-elements-width-height-within-directives-and-component)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef){}

@ViewChild('modal') private modalContent: ElementRef;
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.modalHeight = this.modalContent.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    this.modalWidth = this.modalContent.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
    this.positionLeft = (window.innerWidth - this.modalWidth) / 2 + "px";
    this.positionTop = (window.innerHeight - this.modalHeight) / 2 + "px";
    console.log("on init: "+this.modalWidth)   
}
```

Comment: it should be: `ngAfterViewInit` instead of `ngOnInit` as in your comment

Comment: Can I use the refrence variable inside the component declaration like this <app-hello-world #ref1></app-hello-world >

Comment: @vishnu I don't fully understand the question. What do you want to do with `#ref1`?

Comment: I want the offset height of it.

Comment: @vishnu You can use `'ref1'` instead of `'modal'` in my example, but I wonder if this is really what you mean, because it seems too obvious.