# How to get style of DOM elements in Angular?

Tags: angular

I know you can use ngStyle to *set* styles of an element. But how do I *get* styles of an element (ie, the default styles as rendered by the browser)?

This code doesn't work but expresses what I'm trying to do:

```
<p>TEXT</p>
width of TEXT element is {{textElement.width}}
height of TEXT element is {{textElement.height}}
```

I want the p element to render normally (however the browser wants to, without telling it a width or height). However, I want to know what the rendered width and height are. How do I bind things to capture this?

EDIT: Some people asked what I want to do with the width and height. What I want to do is something like this:

```
<p *ngIf="!isEditing">{{myText}}</p>
<textarea *ngIf="isEditing" [(ngModel)]="myText"></textarea>
```

By default, p is displayed and textarea is not. If the user enters editing mode, p gets replaced by textarea. I wanted to set textarea's width and height to match p's so the transition looks seamless. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the width and height once you get them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2:How to get element's width/height within directives and component?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39813269/angular-2how-to-get-elements-width-height-within-directives-and-component)

Comment: Try something like this.... angular.element(document.querySelector('#lilogin')).removeClass('active');

Answer (score 10):

this can also be done using `@ViewChild`

stackblitz link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-playground-jzgein

component.ts:

```
import {Component, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild('viewChildHook', {static: true}) viewChildHook: ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){
      const value = getComputedStyle(this.viewChildHook.nativeElement).getPropertyValue('--my-variable-name');
      console.log("value", value);

}

}
```

component.html:

```
<div #viewChildHook class="html-dom-element">
    aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
    bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
    cccccccccccccccccccccc
</div>
```

component.scss:

```
.html-dom-element{
  --my-variable-name: 300px;
    width: var(--my-variable-name);
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The best way is to use a directive through which you can get access to the native DOM element to which this directive is applied. Then you can wait until the DOM is rendered in `AfterViewInit` hook and use [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) method to get all computed styles.

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[style-getter]'
})

export class StyleGetter {
  constructor(public el: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnChanges() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth);
  }
}
```

You also should probably hook into `ngOnChanges` hook since often DOM is re-rendered when input bindings change. You can use setTimeout to wait until all styles are computed and DOM is rendered.

You also have to use `offsetWidth` instead of `width`, because:

> offsetWidth returns computed element's width, while el.style.width
>   just returns width property defined in element.style by javascript and
>   does not reflect real element's dimensions.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8133146/difference-between-style-width-and-offsetwidth-in-html).

Comment: Hi! Did you mean `ngOnChanges` hook?

Comment: Hi @MaxKoretskyiakaWizard, shouldn't there be `this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth` instead of `styles.offsetWidth` ?

Comment: @AndreiGătej, why?

Comment: `offsetWidth` seems to be a property of **HTMLElement**, but not of **CSSDeclarationStyles**.(I might have misspelled the last one). Anyway, it worked for me using `this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth`

Comment: getComputedStyle leads to style recalculation on all DOM nodes, major performance issue

Answer (score -1):

The best way is not to do this.

The browser does layout for a living, driven by the HTML and the CSS. Together, they provide a rich set of capabilities for controlling layout, including media queries, flexbox, and many others.

Accessing an element's height and then adjusting this thing over there or moving this thing over there is a slippery slope. Before you know it, you will end up recreating, and redoing, much of the layout work that the browser is designed to do for you.

If you really want to get the height, there are of course ways to do that, as mentioned in other answers. However, before you start down this road, you should make sure that you really want to, and need to.

If you provide a more specific example of what you intend to do with the height once you retrieve it, people here can probably suggest lots of ways to accomplish the same thing without lots of Angular/TS code.

To accomplish what you want with the textarea replacing the `<p>`, you could try this:

```js
let editing = false;

function toggle() {
  document.getElementById('div').classList.toggle('editing', editing = !editing);
}
```

```css
div { border: 1px solid gray; position: relative; }

textarea { 
  display: none; 
  height: 100%; width: 100%; 
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; 
}

.editing textarea { display: block; }
.editing p { visibility: hidden; }
```

```html
<p><button onclick="toggle()">Toggle editing</button></p>

<div id="div">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  
  <textarea></textarea>

</div>
```

As I'm sure you can figure out by looking at the code, the approach is to put both the `p` and the `textarea` within a `div`. The size of the `div` will be governed by the size of the `p`. The `textarea` is positioned absolutely to align exactly with the `div`. When in editing mode, the `p` is set to `visibility: hidden;`, which maintains its position/size in the layout, but hides it, and the `textarea` is set to `display: block;` so it is shown.

Adapted to Angular, and using the same CSS, this would be:

```
// component 
editable = false;

// template
<p><button (click)="editable = !editable">Toggle editing</button></p>

<div id="div" [class.editable]="editable">
  <p>{{myText}}</p>
  <textarea [(ngModel)]="myText"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: I've edited to describe what I'm trying to do. Is there a better way than accessing the width and height?

Comment: This is helpful but I've run into an issue. I also want the text to be arranged in multi-column format, ie. such as by adding "column-width: 8em" to the div's styles. The textarea should follow the same behavior as the text and arrange into columns. However, currently the textarea simply covers the entire div when toggled on, without respecting column layout at all. How can the textarea be made to conform to the column layout?

Comment: @RayZhang I think it's going to be hard to impossible to get the textarea to arrange itself in columns, no matter how you do it. That's just not how textareas work. You might want to experiment with `contentEditable` in that case.